# how to access javaScript Number type property

Tags: javascript, object

In javaScript Object.

```
var person = {
  name: "bengen",
  age: 27,
  5: true
}
```

How can I access the property 5, please?

-_-

Comment: Also have a look at some introductory material: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the access via `[]`:

```
alert( person[ 5 ] );
```

A JavaScript object's properties can be accessed by using `.` or `[]`. The latter is especially useful for numeric keys or in cases, when you have a key identifier stored in another variable.

Comment: Thank you! person[5] , person['5'] , person["5"] all can work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[]`. For example, `person[5]` or `person["5"]`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the square bracket accessor rather than the dot:

```
if(person[5]){
    // if the value is true, do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var person = {
  name: "bengen",
  age: 27,
  5: true
}

console.log(person['5']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Conner, I was rushing to be the first to answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, this should work: `person["5"]`